# Is +15005550006 the only phone number you can buy using test credentials?

Tags: twilio, credentials

For testing Twilio applications, Twilio provides test credentials. You are allowed to buy phone numbers through the API without being charged to your actual account. My application requires that I be able to buy multiple phone numbers. I would like to do this with test credentials.

However, per this documentation [page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials), it seems like the only phone number you can buy is +15005550006. I tried buying other phone numbers, but I keep getting an exception that states that the phone number I'm trying to buy "...is not available."

Is it really the case that only that one number can be bought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Test credentials are for making sure your HTTP calls are being made correctly, they just mock the results of the API so you can make practice calls to it. The idea with test credentials is that if the API call to the fake number works, then your code will work in production.

The test credentials also cause Twilio to return special results for certain resources. For example, you can try to buy the number +15005550001 and it will tell you that the number is invalid. You can see the special examples here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials#test-incoming-phone-numbers-parameters-PhoneNumber

If you need to actually buy numbers with your account to build your application with, you'll need to use your live credentials. If your app is successful purchasing +15005550006 then you can be sure that switching out to real credentials will work.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed to hear. Bummer that test credentials don't match my testing needs.